# Is there a recommendable book about the foundations of artificial intelligence for non-mathematicians?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bibliography

I am not a mathematician but want to dive into AI. I did a search on Amazon and like tens of thousands of books appeared on the shelf (well, almost).

Which one should I pick as a AI beginner with not much mathematical knowledge? I mean I don't want a book that explains everything by formulas only. I had one like that a few years ago and stopped thinking about AI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russel and Norvig is the canonical one.

Comment: This one is recommandable too

Comment: I guess you're talking about **Artificial Intelligence, a Modern Approach**, by Stuart J. Russell and Peter Norvig?

Comment: you can find this book at  http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Approach-Stuart-Russell/dp/0131038052

Answer (score 2):

An introduction to AI by his father would be ["Society of Mind" by Marvin Minsky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671657135).

Answer (score 2):

I bought this book 2 years ago when I wanted to start learn about AI:

[Artificial Intelligence: A Beginner's Guide (Beginners Guide), by Blay Whitby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/185168607X)

It's very basic and everything is explained in a way anyone can relate to. Also it's not a lot to read. A good place to start out to learn the basic concepts.

Comment: I found it to be too light of a treatment, to be honest.

Comment: Really? I found it really good for a person who have no experience in the field or anything related. A good starting point.

Comment: I can't argue that it's a bad starting point.  My impression (and I haven't read it in about that long, so it may be tainted by time) was that it stopped just short of actually explaining the subtopic and passed that off to the references (which I remember being good, so I suppose it's worth it just for those alone).

Comment: +1 for the references, you sold me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this goes into just the right amount of depth:

[Introduction to Artificial Intelligence: Second, Enlarged Edition, by Philip C. Jackson Jr.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048624864X)

There's some mathematics, but it's minimal.  It's a Dover book, so it doesn't cost very much either.

Answer (score 1):

[Practical Artiﬁcial Intelligence Programming With Java, Third Edition, by Mark Watson](http://www.markwatson.com/opencontent/JavaAI3rd.pdf)

A decent amount of code, but not much math. Plus it's free for non-commercial use.